# Why an Observable<Persons[]> can be used as mergeAll input?

Tags: arrays, merge, rxjs, observable, flatten

According to the documentation :

> mergeAll<O extends ObservableInput>(concurrent: number =
> Infinity): OperatorFunction<O, ObservedValueOf>
> Returns
>
> OperatorFunction<O, ObservedValueOf>: A function that returns an
> Observable that emits values coming from all the inner Observables
> emitted by the source Observable.

If I am not mistaken this mean that the mergeAll method Flattens an Observable-of-Observables. So mergeAll takes an Observable-of-Observables as input.

https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeAll

But, according to code sample :

```
personWithAddress$ = this.persons$.pipe(
    mergeAll(), // flatten to Observable<Person>
    
  );
```

If I am not mistaken, we have mergeAll<Persons[]>() where a Observable-of-Observables is expected.

```
persons$ = this.service.get(selectPersons);
         // ^? Observable<Persons[]> where Person = {id: number, name: string}
```

https://dev.to/this-is-angular/managing-array-of-observables-3alf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually, the [docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeAll) state that the signature is:

```
mergeAll<O extends ObservableInput<any>>(concurrent: number = Infinity): OperatorFunction<O, ObservedValueOf<O>>;
```

And `ObservableInput` is:

```
type ObservableInput<T> = Observable<T> | InteropObservable<T> | AsyncIterable<T> | PromiseLike<T> | ArrayLike<T> | Iterable<T> | ReadableStreamLike<T>;
```

And `ObservedValueOf` is:

```
type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T : never;
```

And finally, `OperatorFunction` is:

```
interface OperatorFunction<T, R> extends UnaryFunction<Observable<T>, Observable<R>> { /* [...] */ }
```

Which makes `Observable<T[]>` a valid input as `T[]` satisfies  `ArrayLike<T>` which in turn satifies `ObservableInput<T>`, and thus the input would be `OperatorFunction<T[], T>` which is simply a function of signature `(arg: Observable<T[]>) => Observable<T>`.